# Adding quotes to a single variable

Tags: bash, variables

I want to add double quotes around my variable string, any advice on how I adapt my code? Simple example below

```
#!/bin/bash

variable="variable"
echo $variable
```

I'd like to see the output as

```
"variable"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape the quotes:

`echo \"$variable\"`

Comment: It is a best practice to have an outer-double quote to avoid word-splitting of the contents present